# Setting Date in the Future with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to generate a future date based on a previously set date, but I am getting strange output.

```
var today = new Date(),
    expiration = (today.getTime() + (3*60*1000),
    theFuture = new Date();

//setup future time
theFuture.setDate(expiration);

console.log(theFuture);

//outputs something like:
Tue Jan d) -2147483647 20:33:52 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Why is the date malformed here?
Ultimately I want to compare the dates, but something isn't right here.

Comment: `getDate()` and `setDate()` return and set the day of the month. You're adding 180,000 days to the date, which is 493 years.

Comment: TYPO: I meant to have getTime, not getDate.

Comment: But you're still using `setDate`. So you're setting the day of the month to 1437007985574, which is 3.9 billion years in the future.

Comment: I see, its the setDate, not setTime. I didn't realize thats what I was setting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `setDate` is the day of the month, while the return value of `getTime` is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970. So you're setting the day of the month to something like `1437007985574`, which is almost 4 billion years in the future. You get a nonsensical result because the date formatting functions aren't designed to handle such large dates, and they're overflowing internally.

Since you're using `getTime` to get the time in milliseconds, you should use `setTime` to set it the same way:

```js
var today = new Date(),
    expiration = today.getTime() + (3*60*1000),
    theFuture = new Date();

//setup future time
theFuture.setTime(expiration);

alert(theFuture);
```

Answer (score 0):

getDate() returns day of the month (between 1 and 31). Thats why setDate results in a malformed date